# setOnActionExpandListener and OnActionExpandListener not working

Tags: android, search, actionlistener

Hi Stackoverflow team,

Below is the my code of search view:

```
private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            searchQuery = null;
            updateData();
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) (getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE));
    searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
        searchView.clearFocus();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(onQueryTextListener);
    }
}
```

setOnActionExpandListener and OnActionExpandListener are deprecated and its not working. Can someone help me to fix it with the code?
Thanks in advance